# Clustering with Average Link

Tags: cluster-analysis

I have to sets:

```
A = {(2, 3, 4), (3, 1, 3), (2, 5, 4)}
B = {(4, 4, 4), (3, 7, 3)}
```

I now want to know the Average-Link but i actually dont
know which sets to calculate with.

```
dist_al(A, B) = 1 / (|A| * |B|) * SUM dist(x, y)
```

what is `|A| * |B|` in this example? is it 3 * 2 (Sets in set A * Sets in set B) or is it 9 * 6 (each number)?

If its the first i get:

> `1/6 * (2 + 2+ 2+ 1+ 5+ 1+ 1+ 1+ 1+ 4+ 1+ 3+ 1+ 1+ 1+ 1+ 4+ 3+ 3+ 3+ 2+ 6+ 2+ 1+ 1+ 1+ 4+ 2+ 2+ 2+ 1+ 5+ 1+ 1+ 1+ 1+ 2+ 2+ 2+ 1+ 3+ 1)`

=> 14, 16

If its the second i get

> `1/54 * (2 + 2+ 2+ 1+ 5+ 1+ 1+ 1+ 1+ 4+ 1+ 3+ 1+ 1+ 1+ 1+ 4+ 3+ 3+ 3+ 2+ 6+ 2+ 1+ 1+ 1+ 4+ 2+ 2+ 2+ 1+ 5+ 1+ 1+ 1+ 1+ 2+ 2+ 2+ 1+ 3+ 1)`

=> 1,5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In common mathematical notation, `|A|` is the number of elements in the set `A`.
I.e. `|{ Apple, Banana, Obama }| = 3`, assuming that these are three different objects.

As there are 6 pairwise distances, dividing by 6 also is the obvious choice.

Note that there exists two different "average" linkages. The names differ slightly from book to book. UPGMA and WPGMA are somewhat clearly defined, look these up!

Oh, and note that when implementing hierarchical clustering, one will usually *not* compute it using this formula, but instead use an update formula based on the previous results.

The average linkage (using Euclidean distance) therefore is:

```
sum(2.2360679775 4.24264068712 3.31662479036
    6.0          2.2360679775  2.44948974278)/6
= 3.4134818625433332
```

Comment: i know that |{ Apple, Banana, Obama }| = 3
i dont know what |{ (Apple, Banana, Obama), (one, two, three) }| is
postet in my example above. it makes a big difference if it is 6 or 2

Comment: Use the mathematical definitions, instead of making up your own.

Comment: my question is still not answered. also did you ignore the mathematical definitions too: "As there are 6 pairwise distances, dividing by 6 also is the obvious choice."
So you arent sure as well?

Comment: I am sure. Because that is how `|A|*|B|` is defined in any math book I have seen.

Answer (score 0):

To find the distance between two clusters in an avgerage-linkage algorithm, you have to calculate the euclidian distance for every data point in set A against every data point in set B. Then take the average of all distances.
So:
betweenClusterDistance = ((euclidinDistance((2, 3, 4), (4, 4, 4)) + euclidinDistance((3, 1, 3), (4, 4, 4)) + euclidinDistance((2, 5, 4), (4, 4, 4)) + ... + euclidianDistance((2, 5, 4), 3, 7, 3))) / (number of euclidian distance calls))

Take a look at the following code:

```
public static double findClusterDistance(ClusterObject cluster1,
        ClusterObject cluster2) {
    double distance = 0.0;
    int itt = 0;
    for (DataObject data1 : cluster1.getClusterList()) {
        for (DataObject data2 : cluster2.getClusterList()) {
            itt++;
            distance += getEuclidianDistance(data1.getDimensions(),
                    data2.getDimensions());
        }
    }
    return distance / itt;
}

public static double getEuclidianDistance(List<Double> list1,
        List<Double> list2) {
    double euclidianDistance = 0.0;
    double partialDistance = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
        partialDistance += Math.pow(list2.get(i) - list1.get(i), 2);
    }
    euclidianDistance = Math.sqrt(partialDistance);
    return euclidianDistance;
}
```